# How to add and remove a class from an input label using refs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, classname

I have a React component that includes an input element and a corresponding label element. I want to add and remove a class from the label element based on whether the input element has a value or not. I'm using useRef to reference the input element in my component. How can I add and remove the class from the label element using useRef?

Here's my current code:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleBlur = () => {
    const inputValue = inputRef.current.value;
    if (inputValue === "") {
      // TODO: remove "active" class from label element
    } else {
      // TODO: add "active" class to label element
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="my-input">My Input</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="my-input"
        name="my-input"
        ref={inputRef}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've omitted the implementation for adding and removing the class from the label element because I'm not sure how to do it using useRef. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, **don't** use a ref for this. It's not the React way to do things - https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#best-practices-for-dom-manipulation-with-refs. Use a state for the current input value and render the class depending on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `ref` for the `<label>`.

```
const labelRef = useRef(null);

<label htmlFor="my-input" ref={labelRef}>My Input</label>
```

Then, use `classList.toggle`.

```js
const handleBlur = () => {
    const inputValue = inputRef.current.value;
    labelRef.current.classList.toggle('active', inputValue !== '');
};
```

However, it is more idiomatic to use state instead, as shown below:

```
const [labelClass, setLabelClass] = useState('');
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const handleBlur = () => {
    setLabelClass(text !== '' ? 'active' : '');
};
return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="my-input" className={labelClass}>My Input</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="my-input"
        name="my-input"
        value={text}
        onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: @Nicke7117 Just a suggestion, it's a better idea to use states in this case. For example, you can create a state variable `isActive` or something like that, and then add a check using ternary operator in the class attribute of the element you want (in this case, the label element).

Comment: @ArRakin It is indeed better to use state. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know but I think that it's not possible since I have multiple of these components in a component, and it would be too much unecessary code to add if I wanted this functionality to all of the same components. @Unmitigated

Comment: @Nicke7117 I've also shown the method using refs at the top of my answer.